# How to make sublime text highlight CUDA C++ syntax

Tags: c++, cuda, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 to write CUDA C++ programs. But when I create the .cu file and open it using Sublime Text, the Sublime Text does not highlight the syntax.
I installed the packages here

```
https://github.com/harrism/sublimetext-cuda-cpp
```

I cd to the Sublime Text directory, git the repository and restart the Sublime Text. However, nothing got changed. What's wrong? Do I need to further configure something after I git the repository to the sublime text directory?
Thank you all for helping me !!!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. You don't seem to be having an issue with your program/code. This means that this is off-topic.

Comment: Recommendation: Never install a package manually via git if it's in Package Control; always use Package Control where possible unless you know a compelling reason not to.To your question; can you describe (or show) what you mean by "does not highlight the syntax"? Is everything white, highlighting some stuff but not like what you expect, etc?

Comment: I said "not highlight syntax" and it means every word is in white color. But as normal sublime style, the keywords like "main", "return", and other C++ keywords shall have special colors. This only happens to source files ended with ".cu". For .cpp and .c files, everything is in the correct style, i.e. colorful keywords. This means sublime text does not support CUDA source files, so that I need plug-ins.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I have solved this problem.

Firstly, install the Package Control introduced by most blogs. Then, as recommended by OdatNurd, I abort the installation via git. Instead, I open the sublime text, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. Then type in "Package Control", then choose "Package Control: Add Repository". We are required to input a url. Input "https://github.com/harrism/sublimetext-cuda-cpp". Press Enter. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> again, type in "Package Control", this time choose "Package Control: Install Package". In the search box, type in "cuda", and choose the name of the CUDA C++ package.

Finally, restart sublime.
Thanks all the answerers!

Comment: You don't need to `Add Repository` at all. Simply [search](https://packagecontrol.io/search/cuda) the Package Control website for `cuda`, select the plugin you want to install, then after choosing `Package Control: Install Package` in the Command Palette, just start typing in the name of the package until you find it. You should only use `Add Repository` if a particular plugin is *not* in Package Control.